# Insert boxed prooftree inside prooftree

Tags: errors, fbox, bussproofs

I'm trying to typeset proof trees with bussproof (`usepackage{bussproofs}`, available on CTAN). My personal favorite notation for explaining the rule of introduction of implications is with boxes, but I seem to not be able to insert boxed proof trees inside proof trees. I really don't understand what happens. The following code works :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\fbox{
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\AxiomC{$B$}
\BinaryInfC{\vdots}
\UnaryInfC{$C$}
\DisplayProof
}

\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\AxiomC{\fbox{Whatever}}
\BinaryInfC{$B \Rightarrow C$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

But not the following :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\AxiomC{\fbox{
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\AxiomC{$B$}
\BinaryInfC{\vdots}
\UnaryInfC{$C$}
\DisplayProof
}}
\BinaryInfC{$B \Rightarrow C$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Neither does :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\fbox{
\AxiomC{$\mathcal{A}$}
\AxiomC{$B$}
\BinaryInfC{\vdots}
\UnaryInfC{$C$}
}
\BinaryInfC{$B \Rightarrow C$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

In these cases, I get a "Proof tree badly specified." error :(

I'm really not that much into LaTeX, so I can't really give more precise indications :/ Feel free to ask anything !

Thanks for reading and hopefully helping me :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippets be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Excuse me. Here is something that compiles~: [see OP, formatting doesn't seem to work here]

Now I'd like the fbox outside to actually be the one inside, but it doesn't work :(

(EDIT : I've put the code in the OP)

Comment: I ended up using another package, prftree. It works fine but the syntax is... a bit heavy ^^